# Extension theory and automorphism extension

Tags: group-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

My  question is motivated by the  following two posts

[On finite 2-groups that whose center is not cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891947/on-finite-2-groups-that-whose-center-is-not-cyclic)

and

[Automorphisms of group extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756001/automorphisms-of-group-extensions)

**Question:**
Assume that $A,B,C$  are there algebraic structures (groups, algebra, banach or  $C^{*}$  algebra). Let we  have  an  extension: $$0\to A \to  B \to C \to  0$$

Assume  that   $A$  is commutative and every automorphism of  $A$ has  an extension to  an automorphism of  $B$. Does it imply that $A\subset Z(B)$,  the  center of $B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, $S_3$ contains a characteristic, abelian subgroup not contained in the centre of the group. Both of the automorphisms of this subgroup extend to (inner) automorphisms $G$.